# Can ontic vagueness not exist?

Tags: existence, reality, objects, vagueness

As far as I can tell, I am going to buy a book on ontic vagueness to work out what it is, but I'm fairly sure it occurs when a vague term refers to something that itself is indeterminate, which may be problematic in various ways.

You can probably conceive of how odd it is to think that some people really are borderline cases of bald, and it's not just a confusion of our defintions and semantics that there are borderline cases. I know very little, ok nothing at all, about non-existent objects, but I would imagine that ontic instances of vagueness would be an object in *some* sense, and it's somewhat live whether or not all objects that are exist (even while the difference between being and existence is a thorny issue).

So that's pretty much all I know, besides the fact that this won't have an easy answer in the literature.

Can ontic vagueness not exist?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you are seeking to better understand things that don't exist?

Comment: maybe @MichaelHall

Comment: Well, the vagueness of that answer would seem to indicate that maybe you are on the way. 
But, how will you know whether you have achieved a goal of understanding things that do not exist?  I'm with the community 'bot on this one though, because your question isn't making any sense.